# Is there any way to use youtubePlayerView in application without extending YoutubeBaseActivity, YoutubePlayerSupportfragment and intent

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using YoutubePlayerView in my application but I am using conductors in application instead not fragments.
I would like to use YoutubePlayerView in my custom view without extending YoutubeBaseActivity and YoutubePlayerSupportFragment.

Comment: used YoutubeBaseActivity did not find any other alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other alternative available to achieve this.

I used YoutubeBaseActivity.